# How to convert org.apache.spark.sql.Column to data types like Long or String

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-graphx

I am new to Scala and Spark. I am trying to load data from **Spark SQL** to build **graphX** vertices however I am facing an error that I don't know how to solve. This is the code:

```
val vRDD: RDD[(VertexId, String)] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(spark.table("sw")))
                                    .map(row => (row("id"), row("title_value")))
```

And this is the error:

```
<console>:36: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId
    (which expands to)  Long
       val vRDD: RDD[(VertexId, String)] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(spark.table("sw")))
                                           .map(row => (row("id"), row("title_value")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There error message is correct you are getting columns returned.  You can pull those values out of the column with the following:

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(spark.table("testme")))
.map(row => (row("id").asInstanceOf[Long],row("name").toString))
```

or maybe:

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(spark.table("testme")))
.map(row => (row("id").asInstanceOf[VertexId],row("name").asInstanceOf[String]))
```